# Hide/Dispose a DrawImage

Tags: graphics, applet, java

I am writing a program that shows a image moving across the screen, however for the assignment I **must** use the drawImage method. I create a new Image called turtle, and then draw the Image at the one point, then I draw it again at a later point, however, the first drawn Image is still visible, how can I hide/make this disappear. I am new to Java so please explain this as simply as possible.

Thanks!

Here is a sample of my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Race extends Applet {

         Image tortoise;

   public void init() {
           setSize(1275,1000);
           tortoise = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "resources/tortoise.png" );



   }

   public void paint( Graphics g) {

           g.drawImage(turtle, 100, 100, this);
           g.drawImage(turtle, 200, 200, this); // Both images are shown.               

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to overwrite its previous position with the background before you redraw it. [`clearRect`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) would be a good option for this.

```
g.drawImage(turtle, 100, 100, this);
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch(InterruptedException e) {}

g.clearRect(100, 100, turtle.getWidth(null), turtle.getHeight(null));
g.drawImage(turtle, 200, 200, this);
```

If you are drawing more than the one image to the screen, you will have to redraw all images which overlap the area you clear, in the correct z order, to maintain the screen state.

Answer (score -1):

Consider what you are doing.  You have a canvas opened up and then you draw something on it.  And then you draw something else on it.  And they both appear.

Now, think about a video game, say, Super Mario Brothers, when there are two Koopas (turtles) on the screen.  The draw(koopa) gets called twice...just like in your code.

In order to make the first turtle disappear, you can do a couple of things...the simplest being clearing the background before you draw the second one.

After that...try moving the turtle with a for-loop instead and only using the drawImage method once (in the loop).

Comment: for-loop would hold the awt event thread. the screen will not be updated correctly

Comment: Thanks for catching that...I really just added that last bit as an afterthought.